# JObject.Parse returns two {{ instead of one { in beginning and end

Tags: c#, api, parsing, json.net, httpcontent

I'm using JObject.Parse and it's not a valid json as it has two {{ in the beginning and two }} at the end instead of only one of each.

Tried catching exception but didn't hit the exception of my try catch.
If I remove the extra { in the beginning and the extra } in the end jsonFormatter/validator webpage says it's okey.

```
  var URL = "https://api.instagram.com................my access token etc";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;

        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(result.Result);
        }
```

So reuslt.Result looks like this: "{\"pagination\": {}, \"data\": [{\"id\".........

and json starts looks like this: {{  "pagination": {},  "data": [    {      "id": "20...............

When copying the json into formatter/validator and removing the extra { in the beginning and the extra } in the end everything is okey. 
So I expect the output json from JObject.Parse should look like this: {  "pagination": {},  "data": [    {      "id": "20...............

I can not understand why I'm getting these extra {} things?

Comment: You really need to start using `async` and `await` in this code, doing `.Result` on tasks can be very dangerous.

Comment: Also, what makes you think you are getting these extra braces? `JObject` is not a string, it's a class.

Comment: after parsing data, you can get data by json["pagination"].....

Comment: - I would love to use async and await, could you please tell me how David?
I don't know why I'm getting the extra braces which is why I posted the question as I need help.

Comment: The two `{{` and `}}` are artifacts of how Visual Studio and VSCode visualize a `JObject`.  I have no idea why it does so but lots of people get confused by it.  If you want to know what the `JObject` really looks like when formatted as JSON, in the Immediate Window, type `Console.WriteLine(json)` and its raw `ToString()` text will be displayed without any "helpful" escaping or visualization artifacts added by Visual Studio / VSCode.